# DFS Setup - The namespace server cannot be added. The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, dfs

I went to DFS Management and added a created a New Namespace.

For the namespace server, I specified my Primary Domain controller (netbios name: `primarydc`).

For the namespace, I enter `Files`.

I use a domain-based namespace (`Windows Server 2008 mode`).

Namespace server: `primarydc`.

Preview of the namespace is `\\mydomain.corp\Files`

I got an error saying `\\mydomain.corp\files: The namespace server \\primarydc\Files cannot be added. The system cannot find the path specified`.

Now when i browse the network shares on the `\\primarydc`, I see a shared folder named Files exists, but when i double click it i get an error from Explorer `The system cannot find the path specified`.

I cannot try again with the same DFS name Files as it says there is already a file share called Files on the primarydc.

How can i remove this file share and go back to a clean state so i can start again?

Any things I should check for that could have caused the initial setup to fail in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to remove the share by logging on to the primary dc, typing the unc in explorer to bring up the share `\\primarydc\` and right clicking the `Files` folder -> sharing and removing the sharing tick.

The error was due to a mistake on my part, when setting the dfs root path I have used `D:\DFSRoot` instead of `C:\DFSRoot` and since the D:\ drive didn't exist on the local DC it was returning path not found.

Unsharing the failed Files share and using a valid path allowed the DFS namespace to be setup properly without issues.